# TouchDelegate for Button inside EditText

Tags: android, button, touch, android-edittext

There is Clear Button inside EditText:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="Enter word here"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bClearText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:onClick="clearEtSearch"
        android:background="@drawable/delete" />
</FrameLayout>
```

TouchDelegate code in MainActivity class:

```
View parent = findViewById(R.id.root);
    bClearText = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bClearText);
    parent.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Post in the parent's message queue to make sure the parent
            // lays out its children before we call getHitRect()
            Rect delegateArea = new Rect();
            Button delegate = bClearText;
            delegate.getHitRect(delegateArea);
            delegateArea.top -= 100;
            delegateArea.bottom += 100;
            delegateArea.left -= 100;
            delegateArea.right += 100;
            TouchDelegate expandedArea = new TouchDelegate(delegateArea,
                    delegate);
            // give the delegate to an ancestor of the view we're
            // delegating the
            // area to
            if (View.class.isInstance(delegate.getParent())) {
                ((View) delegate.getParent())
                        .setTouchDelegate(expandedArea);
            }
        };

    });
```

But TouchDelegate is not working. Touch Area is not expanding. Button is still hard to get clicked. What I am doing wrong?

delete button image:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just put button listener instead of touch to root view? I can't get your question. Please add some more details what do you want to do...

Comment: The problem is the button is very small. I want to add some area for button to be touched with TouchDelegate. But TouchDelegate is not working. I want to know why TouchDelegate is not working.

Comment: You want more space to touch for button, is it the functionality do you want? I can fix it. I don't know Touchdelegate.

Comment: Ok. I need more touch area. It does not matter it is TouchDelegate or other way...

Comment: hehe your answer is totally not working...

Comment: Not wasting time, collecting reputation

Comment: Thats fine... Then why no other person is interested in solving your problem? Coz this problem is not coding problem. Its design and what do you want is hard to fix. So wait for other person who can give you time. From last 1 hr, there are only 12 visits in which one is mine. So you can understand how silly your question is.

Comment: YOu can also use Relative layout for this